# Getting Ip from DefaultHubCallerContext behind a load balancer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a .Net 5 app with a SignalR hub and i want to get the client's IP from the "X-forwarded-for".
My app is behind a load balancer so getting the RemoteIpAddress always returns a 10.x.x.x Ip.

Starting with HubCallerContext i can get a IHttpConnectionFeature from its features

```
var httpReq = Context.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>();
```

And when debugging i can see that the object contains a `RequestHeader`, but i can only access `LocalIpAddress`, `RemoteIpAddress`, `LocalPort`, and `ConnectionId`.

Calling `httpReq.RequestHeaders` does not let me compile the app.

Is there any way of getting the headers from either the `IHttpConnectionFeature` or `DefaultHubCallerContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the middleware `IApplicationBuilder#UseForwardedHeaders` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ForwardedHeadersExtensions`.

This middleware updates `RemoteIpAddress` to the client's IP, as long all proxies update correctly the header `X-Forwarded-For` and that the options are correct (We have to either hardcode the number of proxies or tell the IP/network that we can trust).

In your `Startup.cs` add the following middleware to the `Configure` method:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

Then in `ConfigureServices` you have to configure it:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
 ...
});
```

More information about the options and this in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-6.0#forwarded-headers-middleware-options